# Java - Inheritance Different if statements

Tags: java, inheritance

I currently have a super class with the constructor

```
public Bread(double price)
{
    if (price > 0 && price <= 50)
    {
         this.price = price;
    }
}
```

And another class which inhertits the above class with the constructor:

```
public TigerBread(double price)
    {
        if (price > 0 && price <= 100)
        {
             this.price = price;
        }
    }
```

As you can see they both have different price ranges, however when creating a TigerBread with a price greater than 50, I also need it to be fed into the super class Bread which has a range of 0 - 50, is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: This does not make a lot of sense to me. Why would you need to pass it to the super class? And the short answer is no. A super constructor call must always be the first staement in your constructor. You could however use a setter to set it in the super class, but I think you're probably confused about how inheritence works.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You need one extra method to check/set the price and then override this method for your `TigerBread` class.